# RegEx for matching specific HTML Entity pattern (Emoji)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am working in this regular expression to match exactly the following pattern. The issue is that if it is exceeded, the pattern should not be considered:

I want exactly 6 digits starting with #, but if I write {5} returns true. Then the same happens with ; I want exactly one and to be at the end. Also, I don't know how to use here the $ to specify the final character.

```
 if(preg_match(('/^(#)+([0-9]{6}){1}(;)/'),"#128515;")){
     return true;
  }
```

SHOULD BE IN THIS FORMAT:

```
#128515; for #DDDDDD; not ##DDDD;;
```

Exactly 6 digits start with one `#` and finish with one `;`

Comment: Try using anchors `^` and `$` like `^#[0-9]{6};$` You can omit `{1}` and if you don't need the capturing groups `()` you can omit those as well.

Comment: Please show us some proper examples of strings you want and don't want to match. Since you're asking about the regex, we can't really have it as a reference for what you want.

Comment: YES! This is applicable for a string, separated with spaces. Now, it should start with # (not repeat), followed by exactly 6 digits and to finish with exactly ; at the end.  EXAMPLE: STRING #DDDDDD; STRING. D for digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will return 1 when it matches given subject and if you have 6 digits, it can match 5 as well when there is no ending semicolon as there is no ending boundary set.

You could add anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the string so it matches exactly 6 digits.

From your pattern you can omit `{1}` because the group is already matched 1 time.
If you don't reference to the groups in the code you could also omit them and just us a match only.

You could use:

```
^#[0-9]{6};$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `#` Match #
- `[0-9]{6};` Match 6 digits
- `$` Assert end of string

Your code could look like

```
if(preg_match(('/^#[0-9]{6};$/'),"#128515;")){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So the meta character + can we omit it? Why? Thank you :)

Comment: The `+` is a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) which repeats 1+ times so that would match `#128515;` and `##128515;` and `######128515;` etc